# Conectar Php con SQLServer 2000

Tags: php, sql-server

```
<?php
$server = "10.7.0.202";
$database = "GERENCIA";
$user = "sa";
$password = "";
$conexión = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=$server;Database=$database;", $user, $password);
?>
```

Busco conectar a un servidor MS SQL Server 2000, usando `odbc_connect`, pero creo que no está detectando el driver.

¿Cuál es la manera correcta de instalar el driver y hacer la conexión? O ¿qué me falta?:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function odbc_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\atcreporte\config\sqlsrvr.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\atcreporte\config\sqlsrvr.php on line 17

Comment: Por favor, ¿podrías proporcionarnos qué software y versión de servidor web usas, qué versión de PHP y el sistema operativo y versión? Gracias. En debian wheezy/jessie se arregla ejecutando [`apt-get install php5-odbc`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/php5-odbc) y en ubuntu [`apt-get install php7.0-odbc`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/php7.0-odbc).

Comment: La versión de php con la que buscaba trabajar es 7.1.7 por ahora desde mi pc local siendo el servidor web, con windows 10, El sistema operativo donde esta la base de datos es windows server 2003 standard edition. La versión de sql server es 2000.

Comment: ¿Es algún paquete "todo en uno" como xampp o wamp? ¿O es una instalación propia sobre un apache o IIS propio?

Comment: el servidor web que tengo en mi pc si es xampp, el de sql server 2000 si es un paquete en uno trae: analysis manager, enterprise manager,  y query analyzer.

Comment: Si es xampp entonces ya lo llevas incluido pero sólo necesitas activarlo poniendo esto en el `php.ini`: `extension=php_odbc.dll`. Después reinicia apache. Prueba y me dices si te funcionó.

Comment: ahora me aparecio: 
'Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][Administrador de controladores ODBC] No se encuentra el nombre del origen de datos y no se especific� ning�n controlador predeterminado, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect in C:\xampp\htdocs\atcreporte\config\sqlsrvr.php on line 17'

Comment: ¿Podrías crear un origen de datos de usuario desde el panel de control de Windows? ¿Cómo se llama allí el controlador? ¿Has probado a usar un origen de datos creado ahí en vez de crear una dsn? Prueba con `driver={SQL Server};server=$server;database=$datadase`.

Comment: si conecto asi, ahora tengo una duda: ¿con que versión de php esta trabajando el driver? y si aún son soportadas las funciones que ocupa dicho driver:

Comment: Con toda la información que me has facilitado he redactado una respuesta. Espero que sea lo que buscabas :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Descripción del problema

Mensaje de error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: **Call to undefined function `odbc_connect()`** in  ...

Significado:

La función `odbc_connect` no existe porque no está cargada la extensión necesaria.

### Instalación de PHP/ODBC en Linux

Dependiendo de la distribución Linux usada habrá que hacer uso del gestor de paquetes específico de cada una para instalar el necesario.

En el caso de distribuciones basadas en RedHat (como CentOS, Oracle Linux, etc), Debian (Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Guadalinex, etc) y SUSE (OpenSUSE) el paquete se llama [`php-odbc`](https://pkgs.org/download/php-odbc) y el comando necesario para realizar la instalación (como `root`) varía dependiendo de la distribución:

```
apt-get install php-odbc    # Debian Stretch / Ubuntu 16.04 LTS / etc
yum install php-odbc        # Oracle Linux 7 / Fedora 27 / etc
zypper install php5-odbc    # OpenSUSE 42.3
```

### Instalación de PHP/ODBC en Windows

Dependiendo del paquete o distribución descargado (como [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/) o [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/)) todo lo necesario va incluido pero no está activado por defecto.

Para activar las extensiones de PHP/ODBC debes agregar la siguiente línea en el archivo `php.ini`:

```
extension=php_odbc.dll
```

Tras hacerlo debes reiniciar el servidor apache para que surtan efecto los cambios.

### Nombre de los controladores ODBC disponibles en Windows

Para obtener un listado de los controladores disponibles instalados en Windows se debe inspeccionar la siguiente clave del registro:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers
```

Para obtener un listado desde línea de comandos se puede ejecutar la siguiente instrucción:

```
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers"
```

Cuya salida de ejemplo sería:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers
    SQL Server    REG_SZ    Installed
    SQL Native Client    REG_SZ    Installed
    IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY1    REG_SZ    Installed
    IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER    REG_SZ    Installed
    BMC ODBC for PostgreSQL ANSI (Default)    REG_SZ    Installed
    BMC ODBC for PostgreSQL UNICODE (Default)    REG_SZ    Installed
    BMC ODBC for Oracle (Default)    REG_SZ    Installed
```

Por lo que tu cadena de conexión debería ser:

```
$conexión = odbc_connect(
    "Driver={SQL Server};Server=$server;Database=$database;",
    $user,
    $password
);
```

También puedes ver los disponibles y la versión del controlador a través de "Orígenes de datos ODBC (32/64 bits)" en la pestaña "Controladores":

[image: Orígenes de datos ODBC]